# В Python необходимо добавить хешированные файлы в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, хеширование

Есть скрипт, он из папки берёт 256 файлов и хеширует их, получается 256 строк. Необходимо эти строки **добавить в список**, я пробовал .split() Но почему-то выходит матрица а не обычный список.

```
import glob
import hashlib

filenames = glob.glob("E:/prog/*.data")
list=[]
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
        data = inputfile.read()
        all = hashlib.sha3_256(data).hexdigest()
        print(filename, hashlib.sha3_256(data).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменял название переменных, т.к. [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) и [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) являются именами встроенных функций. И добавил добавление в список

Пример:

```
import glob
import hashlib

filenames = glob.glob("E:/prog/*.data")
items = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
        digest = hashlib.sha3_256(data).hexdigest()
        print(filename, digest)
        items.append(digest)

print(len(items), items)
```